# What do STM32 Cube MX USB Power Parameters do?

Tags: usb, stm32

I am working with an USB Full Speed Interface on an STM32G431. The MCU is connected to a PC through USB. Generally it works, I can send and receive data. In Cube MX I find some "Power Parameters" where I have difficulties to understand what they do:

[image: USB Power Parameters]

Battery Charging seems obvious. Since I don't have any battery charging features in my project, this is not relevant for me.

As far as I know "Link Power Management" enables the STM32 to negotiate with the PC about power requirements. I read somewhere else, that this should be enabled, when the MCU can be powered from two sources (USB and internal power). Since I can power the device from two sources, I enabled it, and it seems to work.

The issues comes with the "Low Power" Parameter. If I enable this, the MCU crashes when I download the flash file to the MCU, I can not halt and reflash in CubeIDE. I have to do a full chip erase before I can use it normally again. The Reference Manual is to cryptic for my taste. I only can try to guess how these parameters are linked to the USB control register (USB_CNTR) [RM0440 Rev 7, Page 2018 ff, 45.6.1 Common registers]. I asume that "Low Power" is connected to Bit 2 "LP-Mode" and for me it reads like, this should be set during runtime to reduce power consumption to a minimum, but not during init?

Can someone explain to me (newbie version please), what the "Low Power" and "Link Power Management" params do in my scenario (STM32 connected to PC as Virtual COM Port)? Or has eventually someone a link to a tutorial where these parameters are explained? I could not find anything, that would help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Low power mode is used when the application is run on batteries, and it might save energy when the microcontroller is not being used. Like IoT sensor that samples very hour or so the ADC to send over radio, then it might be put in low power until the next hour to start over the sampling and sending process.

Once the application enters in low power, it might have several side effects, like stopping MCU, disabling flash and peripheral or losing data in RAM.

I think there are 7 modes and the engineer needs to select one based on power requirements.

It looks like your application is entering in low power and stopping the USB peripheral.